# How to solve $\int\frac{2x}{x^2-2x+1}dx$ using improper fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How would one solve $\int\frac{2x}{x^2-2x+1}dx$ using improper fractions? I tried setting up the integral as equal to
$\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}$, but I'm not getting any answer and I don't know what to do. Any assistance you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first decomposition setup is correct, since your denominator is $(x-1)^2$. In general, if you have $(x-a)^m$, you will have

$$\frac{A_1}{(x-a)^1} + \frac{A_2}{(x-a)^2} + \cdots + \frac{A_m}{(x-a)^m}$$

Comment: What did you do after setting "the integral equal to..." If there are no step, no one can tell you where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it using Partial fractions and get the correct answer. Indeed
$$\int \frac{2x}{( x-1)^{2}} \ =\ \int \frac{A}{( x-1)} +\int \frac{B}{( x-1)^{2}}$$
Solving for $A$ and $B$ by plugging in $A(x-1)+B = 2x$, we get $x(A-2) + B-A = 0$, thus $A=B=2$.
Thus
$$\int \frac{2}{( x-1)} +\int \frac{2}{( x-1)^{2}} \ = 2\ln|x-1| -\frac{2}{( x-1)}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler case of partial fraction decomposition. This can be done without setting $\frac{2x}{x^2-2x+1} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{(x-1)^2}$. I'll show you.

$$\begin{align} \int \frac{2x}{x^2 - 2x + 1}\ dx  &= 2\int \frac{x}{(x-1)^2}dx\\& =  2 \int \frac{x- 1 + 1}{(x-1)^2}\ dx \\& = 2 \int \frac{x-1}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\ dx\\& = 2 \int \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\ dx\\& =\boxed{ 2 \ln|x-1| - \frac{2}{x-1} + C}\end{align}$$

Comment: The question is how to solve the integral **using partial fraction decomposition**, not "how to solve the integral."

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost What I did is **partial fraction decomposition** only. Converting $\int \frac{2x}{x^2 - 2x + 1}\ dx $ into $2\int \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\ dx $ is what we call **Partial fraction decomposition**. But my method is different from the usual method of partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: [Continue] 

Wikipedia says that
*partial fraction decomposition or partial fraction expansion of a rational fraction (that is, a fraction such that the numerator and the denominator are both polynomials) is an operation that consists of expressing the fraction as a sum of a polynomial (possibly zero) and one or several fractions with a simpler denominator.* 

**And yes,** I converted $\frac{2x}{x^2 - 2x + 1}$ into $\frac{2}{x-1} + \frac{2}{(x-1)^2}$, so I'll call it partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resorting to partial fractions, try this

$$\int \frac{2x}{x^2-2x+1} dx= \int \frac{2x-2+2}{x^2-2x+1}dx$$

which can then be re-written as
$$\int \frac {2x-2}{x^2-2x+1}dx+\int \frac {2}{x^2-2x+1}dx.$$

The first part becomes $$\ln(x^2-2x+1)$$ while the second part is $$ 2 \int \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}dx=-2(x-1)^{-1}.$$

So the final answer is simply
$$\ln(x^2-2x+1)-2(x-1)^{-1}+C.$$

Comment: how did the final answer have an extra $ -2x(x-1)^{-1} $ when you simplified the second part as $ -2(x-1)^{-1}$

Comment: my bad, will correct that